# How to scale function parallel to x-axis

Tags: self-learning, transformation

I got this question on a mini test. The curve $y=\frac{-1}{x^2}$ is stretched parallel to the y-axis with scale factor 2. State the equation of the transformed curve.

I wrote $y=2f(-x)$
How is this wrong?

Comment: MathJaX for formatting

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is almost correct. 
**Hint:** Consider what happens to the function $f(x)$ when you replace in the brackets by -x. You are reflecting the function about the y-axis. Is this nescessary for the question asked?